# Regex para quitar tildes y grave accent de un txt

Tags: c#, regex

Quisiera saber qué expresión regular puedo usar, tengo un txt del cual tengo que quitar las vocales tildadas (Á, É, Í, Ó, Ú), tíldes sueltas (´, `) y reemplazar por la misma vocal sin tilde o espacio (_) pero sin cambiar el hecho que ocupa un solo espacio en el archivo txt. He usado esta definición:

```
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex reg = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("[^a-zA-Z0-9]");

reg.Replace(str, " ");
```

Pero al reemplazar una letra tildada transforma la letra pero agrega un espacio a la derecha y no abarca la tilde sola.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una expresión regular te resultará demasiado costosa en tiempo de ejecución, lo mejor que puedes hacer es usar un encoding para poder reemplazar aquellos caracteres tildados:

```
string text = "Estó es uná cádená con tildés";
byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-8").GetBytes(text);
string cleanText = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(tempBytes);
```

El resultado será el siguiente:

> Esto es una cadena con tildes

Acá puedes ver un ejemplo probado en [Rextester](https://rextester.com/OLKNH45787).

Comment: Complementando con un replace para filtrar el "grave accent" ( ` ) y cambiarlo por un espacio funcionó como deseaba.

Answer (score 0):

Una solución podría ser capturar además los posibles espacios que haya antes y después de los caracteres que quieres remplazar. De esta manera eliminarás múltiples blancos y al sustituir te quedarás con solo uno.

También puede ser buena idea añadir un cuantificador `+` a la búsqueda de caracteres no permitidos. De esta manera, si hay dos tildes seguidas no te quedarán dos espacios juntos. Por ejemplo en: `un ´árbol´`

Prueba con la siguiente expresión regular: `\s*[^a-zA-Z0-9]+\s*` y sustituye por un blanco:

**Entrada:**

```
Estó es uná cádená con tildés
y esto son tildes sueltas: una ` tilde
y otra ´. Y ahora vienen más datos.
```

**Salida:**

```
Est es un c den con tild s y esto son tildes sueltas una tilde y otra Y ahora vienen m s datos
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/EPBIok/2/)